# Something similar to DDD debugger for Windows?

Tags: windows, gratis, debugging

I really like the [DDD debugger](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/), because it offers a visual representation of data structures, like this:

[image]

Googling returned no build for Windows, probably because it is a front end for the GNU debugger (although there *is* a Windows port of that).

I guess that I could use DDD with Cygwin, but I always have trouble getting X-windows working with Cygwin.

In any case, I would prefer a pure Windows solution without Cygwin.

Does anyone know of such a beast? And free, please, not commercial.

---

[Update] a few years later, and in [a Dr Dobbs article](http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/visual-debugging-with-ddd/184404519) I read

> Nor DDD for Microsoft and Borland compilers, either, because their
>   debugging information is not understood by GDB

So, it looks like the answer, sadly, is NO.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574456/windows-version-of-the-gdb-frontend-ddd

Comment: +1 but, it is not free. And, see the comment to the the accepted answer; is is indeed a debugger front end, but is not DDD. I.E, it cannot display a linked list as shown above.

Comment: Maybe ddd can be built with mingw?

Comment: Maybe? If you don't know, why post? Maybe it can be done with a lump of cheese ...

Comment: [MS has opened PDB source code](http://blog.llvm.org/2017/08/llvm-on-windows-now-supports-pdb-debug.html), so now Clang understands that format and can interact with Windows debuggers although I don't know if DDD works with lldb or not. IMHO linked list isn't commonly used (and [shouldn't be used in general](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/25xpre/bjarne_stroustrup_why_you_should_avoid_linked/)), so debugging linked lists is not very useful compared to visualized debugging other data structures, which Visual Studio is good at. However it's indeed useful for tree structures

Comment: [Visualization Tools for Debugging Simple C and C++ Data Structures](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229012081_Visualization_Tools_for_Debugging_Simple_C_and_C_Data_Structures), [Is there an open source C visual debugger for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/431000/995714)

Answer (score 2):

You could try Gnat Programming Studio (https://www.adacore.com/community) which is an IDE which supports Ada, C and C++ (and more)

Like all IDEs, you can create projects and debug them, but you can also load executables directly. If the path of the sources match the source on the disk, it will work with a default project, which describes easily in a pseudo-Ada file:

```
project Default is
    for Source_Dirs use ("src");
    for Object_Dir use "obj";
    for Main use ("main.c");
    for Languages use ("C");
end Default;
```

It has a graphical gdb interface and a graph display similar to DDD / Eclipse (depends on the versions), and Windows native version (no Cygwin). You can also type commands directly in the gdb console.

The showcased version is the professional edition, but the free version is released yearly and gets the pro features, just a little later.

In the screenshot below, I have tried `graph display n` which is a structure of my program.

```
typedef struct node_
{
  struct node_ *next;
  int v;
} Node;
```

[image]

It may not be what you want (since it looks more like Eclipse debug), but it used to look very much like DDD before (and they probably thought it was obsolete). I'll investigate more to see if the old graph display is still available, in the meanwhile you have a free/relatively lightweight debugger that doesn't require an Eclipse setup.

EDIT: you can also try the previous release of Gnat Programming Studio downloadable here:

https://www.adacore.com/download/more

select x86 (32-bit) and year 2017 (in 2018 they removed the graph display, bummer)

My example is a bit of a mess but with some work (using "dereference pointers" wisely) you could achieve something.

[image]

Comment: That looks good, but can it display a linked list as per my question? If your `vp` structure contained a pointer to another structure, what would I see (can you post an example, please?) I suspect that it would be a tree, and maybe I could live with that, as it doesn't look like I am going to get a diagram, as with DDD. If your new picture looks good, I will upvote and award the answer.

Comment: let me create a linked list example. I must admit I never tried that.

Comment: done, the result is somehow not what you're expecting, but older versions may be a match. I've asked the authors.

Comment: That is certainly better than anything else that I have ever seen on Windows (@Izzy why can't I see the "accept" button?). If you can find something that looks even more like DDD, then I will add a bonus. Thanks; I can see you becoming a valued member of our community :-)

Comment: Lolx! Izzy forget it - this post looks so much like one of mine, that I thought it was. I have been looking for something like this for years. @Jean let me know if you can find something more like DDD; in any case, I will give you a bonus, but if it is more graphical, it will be a bigger bonus :-)

Comment: you don't have to accept since it's not exactly what you asked for, that's fine by me. yes GPS (Gnat Programming Studio) is highly underrated because it is originally done for Ada, but now (and with my zillion bugreports) it's becoming very good in C and faily good at C++ (thanks to clang parsing engine). It also doesn't need the cumbersome workspace and complex setup Eclipse needs. I have to test the free version / check older ones, though (even if using older versions isn't so good because you don't benefit from bugfixes)

Comment: Ha ha - I had actually forgotten using Gnat - way back in '00 to '04 for Ada 95. happy days!  If you have a good rapport with the Gnat team, please ask them to add diagrams, like DDD does. Since it is FOSS, they may be able to reuse a lot of code.

Comment: They used to have those diagrams. I have asked a question for the support team to see how to get them back or whatever. And I also took time to test the free version of GPS and it's very very close to the professional version (I didn't update the screenshots though)

Comment: having looked at the [feature comparison](https://www.adacore.com/gnatpro/comparison) I can't see that I really need a paid version. I will give it a try for (embedded) C and C++. Thanks for the recommendation

Comment: the paid version is just more up to date for bugs & features. The free version is released once a year. that's the only difference but a big one :)

Comment: @Mawg I have updated my answer. There's an older version that may be very close to your needs.

Comment: Excellent! I can't thank you enough for this. Not can I understand why they took that feature out

Comment: well, they took it out probably to make it look more like Eclipse... (which sucks)

Comment: Why not just make it Eclipse based, with a bunch of plug-ins? That's what everyone else seems to do

Comment: because they have their own IDE for a while now, long before Eclipse became "useable" for C. The problem of Eclipse is that damn workspace and the complexity it carries. They _have_ a plugin, but for .gpr project management, not for debug. GPS uses a project file (like borland and "ancient" IDEs) which allows to open project & build. No need for damn binary workspaces that you have to recreate everytime you change your account/machine.