# A Visual Studio tool to generate "relation map" among the C structs of a big c project

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am working on a big C project. I am using Visual Studio to browse the source code. There are many C structs in the project and they are inter connected to each other. So I am wondering if there's a tool can generate a diagram of the struct relations. For example, which references whose field. This may give me a better overview of the whole project.

Answer (score 2):

While there are some Visual Studio components that provide the sort of information that you are asking for they tend to be limited to specific versions of VS.

I would suggest using [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) - it is a free tool that can generate various formats to document C, C++ and other code.  A good option is to have it generate html documentation, with diagrams such as uses and used by diagrams.  You can use DoxyWizard to configure and doxygen for a given project and save the configuration, (be sure to select the "document undocumented source" option but once this is done you can include the document build step into your project build process.

If you select .svg format for the diagrams in the web pages the blocks for functions or classes will be links to the generated documentation for that function and you can optionally have links to the code.

For the optimum diagram generation you also need to install [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) and tell doxygen where it is installed.

- Both tools are available free and are free to use in commercial environments as well as private/academic.
- Both are cross platform and will work on Windows, OS-X & Linux.
- DoxyGen will work with ***any*** code project in any of the following languages:

  - C, C++, Objective-C, C#,
  - PHP, Java, Python,
  - DL (Corba, Microsoft, and UNO/OpenOffice flavors),
  - Fortran, VHDL, Tcl,
  - and *to some extent* D

Answer (score 0):

***Must*** you use VS?

If you can use Linux, even in a VM, then I ***highly*** recommend [the DDD debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/).

This pitcure will show you why:

[image]

The graphics at the top (a linked list in this case) are generated directly from your data at run-time.

Whtat do you think? Is that worth swapping o/s for?

Alas, I have searched for years and cannot find [a Windows port](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7532/something-similar-to-ddd-debugger-for-windows) of the debugger :-(

Comment: VS can show nested structures just fine, and it has natvis for customized debugging, so I don't see any advantage of DDD

Comment: Can you post a link to this "natvis"!? It sounds interesting

Comment: OIC, it's https://simoncoenen.com/blog/programming/Natvis  Yes, that does look useful. Doesn't seem to help that much, though, when you are asking for "a tool can generate a diagram of the struct relations" - or did I miss something? I really liked the way that DDD let me click my way through a linked list

Comment: of course VS can show you a linked list. Just click the `next` field and it'll expand the pointed structures. You can do that recursively indefinitely

Comment: Thanks. Sounds great! Not a "diagram", but I can certainly navigate. That will do.